# Unexpected behavior while using kafka commands in CLI

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to get some hands on `Kafka CLI`. But when I run the below `cmds` I am not able to see any outputs. It's as if the cmds are not being recognized in the first place. Below is my `server.properties` and `zookeeper.properties`. Am I missing something? I am using **kafka version 2.8.0**

```
kafka-topics.sh  // opens up another cmd terminal but nothing shows up in there
kafka-topics.bat // It just moves to next line, without any output
```

**server.properties**

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
log.dirs=D:/Tools/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/data/kafka
```

Rest all properties are as it is,  I haven't changed anything

**zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=D:/Tools/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/data/zookeeper
```

Also the kafka and ZK both are running on respective ports

Comment: Dont run Kafka "on Windows". Start here https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the directory name of Kafka  from `kafka_2.13-2.8.0` to just `kafka` and try running your zookeeper and kafka . For some reasons , windows consider `kafka_2.13-2.8.0` as long name and shuts down the CLI.

Change the same in all properties file as well.